# What is a good reference to study Whitney stratification in English

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-topology

I am interested to study Whitney Stratifications. So far, the best reference to introduce this topic is [ENSEMBLESSEMI-ANALYTIQUES](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/michel.coste/Lojasiewicz.pdf), but it is in French.

Where can I find a good reference for Whitney Stratifications in English?

Comment: What in particular do you want to know about Whitney stratifications? The paper of Lojasiewicz that you mentioned is about Whitney stratification for semianalytic sets; a good reference for this is Terry Wall's note "Regular stratifications"

Comment: Dear @Balarka Sen thanks for the info.

Comment: Try this: https://hal.science/hal-03186972/document
(David Trotman. Stratification theory. Cisneros-Molina José Luis, Dũng Tráng Lê, Seade José (Eds.). Handbook of Geometry and Topology of Singularities I, 2020. hal-03186972)

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend Pflaum's "Analytic and Geometric Study of Stratified Spaces" for an organised, modern treatment.